# Result not fetching to Spinner from PHP API, MySQL to Android Studio

Tags: php, android, mysql, xampp

```
package com.example.swachkaryalaya;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toolbar;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;
import com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.app.FragmentManager;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
 {

public Spinner spinner;
public JSONArray result;

public ArrayList<String> officelist;
ArrayAdapter<String> officeadapter;
RequestQueue requestQueue;

public TextView textView2;
public TextView textView3;
public TextView textView4;
public TextView textView5;


 ProgressDialog progressDialog;
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    requestQueue= Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

    spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
  
     String url= "http://10.184.200.4:801/skPhp/officeApi.php";

  

    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

                   try {
                       JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("result");

                for(int i=0; i<jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    String officeName = jsonObject.optString("office_name");

                    officelist.add(officeName);
                  
                    officeadapter= new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,officelist);
                    officeadapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                    spinner.setAdapter(officeadapter);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    },

            new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

        }
    });
     RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    //requestQueue.add(JsonObjectRequest);
}
}
```

Does not get any err during Compilation time, But the Spinner is not population data while running in device.
Please give the possible solutions.

My Manifest is as follows

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 package="com.example.dataentryapp">
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

 <application
    android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.DataEntryApp">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

</application>
```

PHP API is working fine Using POSTMAN as well as in Browser

result not fetching data

The Spinner not fetching Data while running in device

My PHP API is as follows.

```
<?php 

require_once('dbConnect.php');

header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header("Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8");
$json = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);

$sql = "SELECT office_name FROM officetable";

$r = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);


$result = array();

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r)){
    array_push($result,array(
      'office_name'=>$row['office_name']
    
     ));
 }

  echo json_encode(array('result'=>$result));




   mysqli_close($conn);
  ?>
```

Comment: Why are you re-setting your adapter inside the loop?

Comment: you mean which line to me removed?